# send _POST in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question is this possible, I have the following code;

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".modalNav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behaviour
        var url = this.href;
        $("#ModalLoader").load(url);
    });
});
</script>
```

Which when a user clicks a link with the `modalNav` class it loads the link in the div.
I am wondering if it possible to send a POST variable when a link is clicked. for example something like this;

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".modalNav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behaviour
        var url = this.href;
        $("#ModalLoader").load(url);
        $_POST['key'] = '1234';
    });
});
</script>
```

so that on the page that is loaded within the div will be able to reference the posted key. this needs to be POST and not a GET.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt tested it but it should works

```js
$(function(){
    $(".modalNav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = this.href;
        $.post(url, { key: '1234' }, function(data) {
            $("#ModalLoader").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

you can also learn more about [Jquery Post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: I get the following error when I try to use this, `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: im edited it, now it should works fine @LewisTyler

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )

and

> Request Method
>
> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Thus:

```
$("#ModalLoader").load(url, { key: 1234 });
```